# Selecting rows where a column is null

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables.

```
submission(submissionID, teamID)  
team(teamID, teamNames)
```

I have 2 records inside team: `(2, john)` and `(3, peter)`

inside submission i have: `(3,3)`

When i use this:

```
select teamName, t.teamID
from team t
inner join submission s on t.teamID = s.teamID
where submissionID is null
```

it return no result back

I have seen some of the example of selecting column when is `null` but it doesn't work for me.

[MySQL: selecting rows where a column is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3536670/mysql-selecting-rows-where-a-column-is-null)

[Select rows where column is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369041/select-rows-where-column-is-null)

Comment: change the `inner join` to `left join`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to find teams without submissions, use an *outer* join:

```
select teamName, t.teamID
from team t
LEFT join submission s on t.teamID = s.teamID
where submissionID is null
```

Teams with no matching rows in submission will still be returned with a left join, but all columns from the joined table will be null.

The where clause filters the results *after* the join is made, so specifying null for a non-null column of the joined table will only return joins that missed.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the mysql but in oracle you can use Outer joins
There are 3 types of outer join

1.Left Outer Join
2.Right Outer Join
3.Full Outer Join

And you can either use a full outer join:-

select * from submission s full outer join team t
on (t.teamID = s.teamID);